# Реализация Drag&Drop функционала в Андроид

Tags: java, android, drag-n-drop, android-drawable

Нужно реализовать, чтоб в основном потоке можно было передвигать один элемент класса Draw, а в другом потоке как-бы летали по экрану еще несколько (есть похожие игры с кубиками).С одним элементом проблем нет, а вот как реализовать остальные, подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
 class MyView extends View {

        Paint paint;


        // координаты для рисования квадрата
        float x = 100;
        float y = 100;
        int side = 100;

        // переменные для перетаскивания
        boolean drag = false;
        float dragX = 0;
        float dragY = 0;

        public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);

            paint = new Paint();

        }


        @Override
        protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
            // рисуем квадрат
            paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            canvas.drawRect(x, y, x+side, y+side, paint);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            // координаты Touch-события
            float evX = event.getX();
            float evY = event.getY();
            Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent: evX: " + evX + " evY: " + evY);
            switch (event.getAction()){
                // касание началось
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // если касание было начато в пределах квадрата
                    if(evX >= x && evX <= x + side && evY >= y && evY <= y + side){
                        // включаем режим перетаскивания
                        drag = true;
                        // разница между левым верхним углом квадрата и точкой касания
                        dragX = evX - x;
                        dragY = evY - y;
                    }
                    break;

                // тащим
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    // если режим перетаскивания включен
                    if(drag){
                        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
                        int w = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
                        int h = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
                        // определеяем новые координаты для рисования
                        x = evX - dragX;
                        y = evY - dragY;
                        if (x > w-100) x = w-100;
                        if (y > h-260) y = h-260;
                        if(x<0) x=0;
                        if(y<0) y=0;
                        Log.d(TAG, "w = " + w + " h = " + h);
                        Log.d(TAG, "x = " + x + " y = " + y);
                        // перерисовываем экран
                        invalidate();
                    }
                    break;
                // касание завершено
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // выключаем режим перетаскивания
                    drag = false;
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
        }
```